# Google documents. I need to edit a document with public link c#

Tags: c#-4.0, google-docs-api

Google documents. I need edit a document with puplic link in c#. Is there anyway?

```
FileStream fs = FileStream("C:\*****.jpg", FileMode.Open); 
DocumentEntry entry2 = service.Update(new Uri(strAlternateUriComesFromServer), fs, "text/plain", null) as DocumentEntry;
```

This code giving error. How can i edit public document.

i got only shared document link and i need to update it.

Comment: you has to give us more details about what have you done and which are the problems that you are facing

Comment: i hope this will be enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the document name or resourceID, and that document is shared with you, and you have the proper read/write access (ACL), you shouldn't have any problem updating the resource.

Normally updating a document with Google Documents API goes something like this:

1. Get the DocumentEntry for the document.  You can construct a DocumentQuery to find the target document based on certain search parameters.  See the documentation here:  [Google Documents List API 3.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#searching_for_documents_and_files)
2. Get the download URL from the DocumentEntry object and download the document to your PC.  Downloading is optional if you're not interested in modifying the original content and just want to upload and overwrite the contents with something you have made locally.
3. Edit the document and update (upload) it to Google Docs.  [Documentation for Updating.](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#updatingchanging_documents_and_files)  Specifically, look at the section called "**Updating document or file content with the resumable protocol.**"  You **must** use the ResumableUploader when uploading anything to Docs now.

Edit to add:
Try to get the DocumentEntry from the public link using the method below:

```
// Public Link contains the resourceID
// example:  https://docs.google.com/file/d/097iZigwrANhGTElvZDdCVmlZNzQ/edit
// resourceID:  097iZigwrANhGTElvZDdCVmlZNzQ
// Get Your Document Entry

string editUri = "http://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full/%3A" + resourceID;
DocumentEntry docEntry = (DocumentEntry)service.Get(editUri);
```

Comment: i have only public link. I have read/write access (ACL). I dont have documents account information. need to update document. I can edit it with internet explorer. Is there any way in c#

Comment: @Yusuf terzi  See my edit above.  I was not able to get the formatting correct here in the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

```
    string editUri = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/file%3A" + resId;

    DocumentEntry docEntry = (DocumentEntry)dsServ1.Get(editUri);
    docEntry.Title.Text = strNewName;
    docEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource("C:\\new.txt", "text/plain");
    ResumableUploader uploader = new ResumableUploader();

    // Start the update process.
    ClientLoginAuthenticator oa = new ClientLoginAuthenticator("Komote", ServiceNames.Documents, strUsername, strPassword);
    uploader.UpdateAsync(oa, docEntry, new object());
```

This code works great. thanx for help.