# How to open and edit a shared google doc in an internal/custom editor using google API?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I've created a Google Service Account and sharing google documents with different users with different permissions(writer, commenter, and reader) using Google.Apis.Docs.v1 and Google.Apis.Drive.v3 Nuget packages.

When I'm sharing, an email generated and user can click on the link in that email and open the document in new google doc tab.

I know we can turn off the email when we share the document. We don't want to redirect the user to google doc tab. Our requirement is to open the document in an internal custom editor and should use the google's editing functionality using their API. Please guide me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable Api for the account which will be run by the .NET application [here](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/dotnet) and follow the code sample.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents), check what are the api commands you need and associate them to your internal editor events. They will enable you to create and edit the document.

You can see more samples [HERE](https://medium.com/@williamchislett/writing-to-google-sheets-api-using-net-and-a-services-account-91ee7e4a291), [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tTiup8q0MC4) with video, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395853/google-documents-i-need-to-edit-a-document-with-public-link-c-sharp).

Comment: The [solution](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents) looks fine, but we have to parse the HTML from the WYSIWYG editor and create a google document, right? How do we implement redlining and collaboration etc? I guess this will be kind of re-invent the google doc

Comment: I can embed the document as an Iframe in the application like src=https://docs.google.com/document/d/{documentId}/edit but if the user is not logged in then it doesn't works. Any help is appreciated

Comment: @KRK What about generating documents in one account which belongs to your application, generating a private link (anyone has access if it knows the link), and load up that one in the iframe?

Comment: I'm trying to generate the link as https://docs.google.com/document/d/@ViewBag.DocId/edit, is there a way to generate private link other than this? Could you please refer that link?

Comment: @KRK Check "alternateLink" property in documentation:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files